# Python - Remove word only from within a sentence

Tags: python, string, replace, str-replace

I am trying to remove a specific word from within a sentence, which is 'you'. The code is as listed below:

```
out1.text_condition = out1.text_condition.replace('you','')
```

This works, however, it also removes it from within a word that contains it, so when 'your' appears, it removes the 'you' from within it, leaving 'r' standing. Can anyone help me figure out what I can do to just remove the word, not the letters from within another string?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe give space after  and before 'you'

Comment: use re: `re.sub(r'\byou\b', '', out1.text_condition)`

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/5gKk4g/1) is an example of It_is_Chris's regex

Answer (score 2):

In order to replace whole words and not substrings, you should use a regular expression (regex).

Here is how to replace a whole word with the module `re`:

```
import re

def replace_whole_word_from_string(word, string, replacement=""):
    regular_expression = rf"\b{word}\b"
    return re.sub(regular_expression, replacement, string)

string = "you you ,you your"

result = replace_whole_word_from_string("you", string)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
  , your
```

**Explanation:**

The two `\b` are what we call "word boundaries". The advantage over `str.replace` is that it will take into account the punctuation too.

In order to create the regular expression, here we use  Literal String Interpolation (also called "f-strings", https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

To create a "f-string", we add the prefix `f`.

We also use the prefix `r`, in order to create a "raw string". We use a raw string in order to avoid escaping the backslash in `\b`.

Without the prefix `r`, we would have written `regular_expression = f"\\b{word}\\b"`.

If you had used `string.replace(' you ', ' ')`, you would have received this (wrong) output:

```
you ,you your
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to replace the word with spaces around it with one space:

```
out1.text_condition = out1.text_condition.replace(' you ', ' ')
```

But note that it wouldn't remove for example `you.` (in the end of the sentence) or `you,`, etc.

Comment: Wow! Did not even think about that. Thank you very much

Comment: I think a strange solution to the punctuation problem would be to somehow remove the punctuation when removing 'you' then somehow add it back at the end, or to recognize punctuation as a space.

Comment: Regex would probably be the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably just to assume there are spaces before and after the word:

```
out1.text_condition = out1.text_condition.replace(' you ','')
```